# SelectedRow and DataBoundItem in WPF as it gets?

Tags: c, wpf, datagrid

I'm passing a basic design of client registration that was made in Windows Form to WPF, and I had a problem in the code that the WPF does not have the selectedRow and then immediately there is also the DataBoundItem.
Does anyone know how I can transcribe this code for WPF ??

```
Customer clienteSelecionado = (dataGridPrincipal.SelectedRows [0] .DataBoundItem as Customer);
```

dataGridPrincipal: is my DataGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the UI for your `DataGrid` is something like this:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dataGridPrincipal" Grid.Row="0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem , Mode=TwoWay}"
              />
```

and the code behind is as follow:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> MyList { get; set; }
    public Customer MyItem { get; set; } // with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyList = YourDataProvider.YourData();
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

then this is what you're looking for:

```
        var clienteSelecionado = dataGridPrincipal.SelectedItems[0] as Customer;
```